# Выборка из нескольких таблиц с сортировкой по времени каждой из них

Tags: mysql

Немного упрощу таблицы. У меня есть 6 таблиц.

1. **modemsInfo**(id, idUser, idGroup, infoText) // информация о модемах
2. **groupModems**(id, idUser, nameGroup) // информация о группах в которой могут быть модемы
3. **data**(idModem, Time, text) // общая информация которую прислали модемы
4. **dataResponseConfig**(idModem, Time, text) // конфигурационная инфа пришедшая от модемов
5. **dataResponseReset**(idModem, Time, text) // результаты сбросов пришедшие от модемов
6. **queueSmsLog**(idModem, Time, text) // смс которые отправлялись модемам

Мне нужно выдать инфу от модемов пользователя. Я выбираю модем и приклеиваю к нему последний ответ (сортирую в колонке(**Time**) и ставлю Limit 1) из таблиц: общий(**data**), конфига(**dataResponseConfig**), сброса(**dataResponseReset**) и смсЛога(**queueSmsLog**). Все работает до момента пока нет одинаковых значений времени(**Time**) в любой таблице. Появляются дубликаты.
Использую такой запрос. Чувствую, что проблема в конце запроса, но как исправить уже знаний не хватает.

```
SELECT gM.nameGroup as nameGroup, mI.infoText, qSL.Time, qSL.text,
       dRC.Time ,dRR.Time, data.Time, data.text
FROM groupModems gM
 left outer JOIN modemsInfo mI ON mI.idUser = gM.idUser AND mI.idGroup = gM.id
 left outer JOIN data ON mI.id = data.idModem
 left outer JOIN queueSmsLog qSL ON mI.id = qSL.idModem
 left outer JOIN dataResponseConfig dRC ON mI.id = dRC.idModem
 left outer JOIN dataResponseReset dRR ON mI.id = dRR.idModem
WHERE gM.idUser = :user_id
AND (data.Time = (SELECT `Time`
                  FROM data
                  WHERE  mI.id = data.idModem
                  ORDER BY `Time` DESC
                  LIMIT 1)
     OR data.Time IS NULL)
AND (dRC.Time = (SELECT `Time`
                 FROM dataResponseConfig
                 WHERE  mI.id = dataResponseConfig.idModem
                 ORDER BY `Time` DESC
                 LIMIT 1)
     OR dRC.Time IS NULL)
AND (dRR.Time = (SELECT `Time`
                 FROM dataResponseReset
                 WHERE  mI.id = dataResponseReset.idModem
                 ORDER BY `Time` DESC
                 LIMIT 1)
     OR dRR.Time IS NULL)
AND (qSL.Time = (SELECT  `Time`
                 FROM queueSmsLog
                 WHERE  mI.id = queueSmsLog.idModem
                 ORDER BY id DESC
                 LIMIT 1)
    OR qSL.Time IS NULL)
```

IS NULL - использовал на случай если вообще нет никакой информации в таблицах c ответами от модемов

Comment: Вам достаточно тех данных, что указаны вверху в блоке select ? т.е. вам нужны несколько полей о самом модеме и из таблиц с полями Time нужно получить только это самое последнее время, другие данные из последних строк из таблиц qSL, dRC, dRR, data не нужны ?

Comment: Да. Я забыл указать. Подправил select. Не из всех text нужен. Tолько из data и qSL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если предположить, что в таблицах вроде dataResponseConfig  есть собственные id записей (а куда же без них, если вдруг нет, добавьте), то выходит что то такое:

```
SELECT gM.nameGroup as nameGroup, mI.infoText,
       qSL.Time, qSL.text,
       (SELECT max(`Time`) FROM dataResponseConfig dRC WHERE mI.id = dRC.idModem) as dRC_Time,
       (SELECT max(`Time`) FROM dataResponseReset dRR WHERE mI.id = dRR.idModem) as dRR_Time,
       data.Time, data.text
  FROM groupModems gM
  left outer JOIN modemsInfo mI ON mI.idUser = gM.idUser AND mI.idGroup = gM.id
  left outer JOIN data ON mI.id = data.idModem
  left outer JOIN queueSmsLog qSL ON mI.id = qSL.idModem
WHERE gM.idUser = :user_id
  AND ( (data.Time, data.id) = (SELECT `Time`, id FROM data
                                 WHERE mI.id = data.idModem
                                 ORDER BY `Time` DESC, id desc LIMIT 1)
     OR data.Time IS NULL)
  AND ( (qSL.Time, qSL.id) = (SELECT `Time`, id FROM queueSmsLog
                               WHERE mI.id = queueSmsLog.idModem
                               ORDER BY `Time` DESC, id DESC LIMIT 1)
    OR qSL.Time IS NULL)
```

P.S. Если все именно так, как описана структура таблиц в вопросе и колонки id нет, то ее стоит добавить, работать с записями без явной уникальности крайне сложно. Тут конечно есть варианты вытаскивать что то вроде `select max(concat(привести_к_строке(Time), text)) ...` и потом обратно разбирать объединенную строку на time и text, но это довольно громоздко выглядит и вообще не удобно.

Comment: Если вы имеете ввиду последний id = записи с последним временем, то я так же думал про это. Но последний айди не будет означать, что время было последнее. Возможна ситуация что модем выдал две смс последовательно и дошли они в разное время. Соответственно в базу сначала может добавится последнее сообщение а потом предпоследнее. И тогда последний id=предпоследнему сообщению.  Или что-то другое вы имели ввиду?

Comment: Спасибо за ответ с кодом. Я в понедельник с ним повожусь и отпишусь о результатах. Теперь буду знать SELECT в SELECT`е что так можно)

Comment: @ДимаЙ так я id использую в запросе как дополнительный атрибут, для гарантии, что запись будет только одна. Конечно я не полагаюсь на то, что id обязательно самый большой. обратите внимание на сравнение `(time, id) = (select time, id ... order by time desc, id desc`

Comment: все супер. Спасибо!